# Como retornar uma tabela, de uma function do POSTGRES?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Olá, estou tentando criar uma função no postgres, que a principio está tudo correto, tirando o retorno da função.

Quando eu executo a função, está retornando todas as linhas, mas tudo somente em um campo como string. E eu preciso que venha no formato de tabela.

**Como vem:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como deveria vim:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> MINHA FUNÇÃO

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fc_comparar_comandos(var1 text,var2 text)
RETURNS TABLE ( p_cmap_id integer,
            p_cmap_cmd_id integer,
            p_cmd_nome text,
            p_cmap_parametro character varying,
            p_cmap_part_number character varying,
            p_cmap_ordem integer,
            p_cmap_level integer,
            p_teste text,
            p_cmd_param text,
            p_testado integer
) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 1
VOLATILE 
ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
    p_cmd     ALIAS FOR var1;
    p_pNumber ALIAS FOR var2;

BEGIN

RETURN QUERY

SELECT   cmap_id,
         cmap_cmd_id,
         cmd_nome,
         cmap_parametro,
         cmap_part_number,
         cmap_ordem,
         cmap_level,
         teste,
         (cmd.cmd_nome || ' ' ||cmd_aprovacao.cmap_parametro) as cmd_param,
         CASE WHEN teste IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as testado
FROM cmd_aprovacao
INNER JOIN cmd ON cmd.cmd_id = cmd_aprovacao.cmap_cmd_id
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT UNNEST(
                STRING_TO_ARRAY(p_cmd, ',')
               ) as teste
            ) t ON t.teste = (cmd.cmd_nome || ' ' ||cmd_aprovacao.cmap_parametro)
WHERE cmap_part_number = p_pNumber
AND cmap_level = (  SELECT MAX(cmap_level)
                    FROM cmd_aprovacao 
                    WHERE cmap_part_number = p_pNumber
                 )
ORDER BY cmap_ordem;

END

$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema não éstá na sua função, está na maneira como ela está sendo chamada.

Quando você chama sua função dessa forma:

```
SELECT public.fc_comparar_comandos( 'ABCD', 'XPTO' );
```

O Postgres retorna um único campo do tipo `RECORD`.

Para se obter as colunas "separadas", que tal chamar a sua função dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM public.fc_comparar_comandos( 'ABCD', 'XPTO' );
```

Ou:

```
SELECT
    p_cmap_id,
    p_cmap_cmd_id,
    p_cmd_nome,
    p_cmap_parametro,
    p_cmap_part_number,
    p_cmap_ordem,
    p_cmap_level,
    p_teste,
    p_cmd_param,
    p_testado
FROM
    public.fc_comparar_comandos('XPTO','ABCD');
```